# How to set hostname using DHCP Option 12

Tags: dhcp, 22.04

I would like to set my hostname using DHCP Option 12 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (it uses networkd by default.) How to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify which Ubuntu product you're talking about, 22.04 is the main product and Ubuntu Core 22 is a *flavor* of 22 and not the same product. There are differences (the *year* or 22 format is supposed to highlight that when contrasted with *year.month* or 22.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Option 12 to work, the DHCP client machine cannot have a static name.

You (usually) start with a static name (`ubustaticname` in this example), what you provided during setup:

```
user@ubustaticname:~$ hostnamectl 
 Static hostname: ubustaticname
...
```

It is saved in a standard config file:

```
user@ubustaticname:~$ cat /etc/hostname 
ubustaticname
```

If you remove that file, you are done.

```
user@ubustaticname:~$ sudo rm /etc/hostname
```

Double check that Ubuntu actually sees this change:

```
user@ubustaticname:~$ hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: n/a                             
Transient hostname: ubustaticname
...
```

And reboot:

```
user@ubustaticname:~$ sudo reboot
```

After reboot, you have the correct hostname (`ubuopt12name` in this example) assigned.

```
user@ubuopt12name:~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: n/a                             
Transient hostname: ubuopt12name
...
```

And that is all.